# How to specific ip and hostname when making http or https requests?

Tags: node.js

```
https.request({
  ip: '127.0.0.1',
  hostname:'internal.hostname_required_for_certificate.com',
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/'
})
```

Above code doesn't work, meaning I need to send a request to 127.0.0.1 while in the request it is sending `https://internal.hostname_required_for_certificate.com/`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually specify a [`Host`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.4) header:

```
const req = https.request({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    headers: {
        'Host': 'internal.hostname_required_for_certificate.com'
    }
}, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.pipe(process.stdout);
});

req.end();
```

Comment: THANK YOU. Can I do the same for `request` module for example something like: `request({url: 'https://internal.hostname_required_for_certificate.com/', host: '127.0.0.1', headers: { host: 'internal.hostname_required_for_certificate.com' }})`

Comment: The idea is to set the HTTP Host header in your request. So as long as you do so, it doesn't matter what library you're using. [Here's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers) how you can set custom headers with request module.

Answer (score 0):

**host**/ip :  A domain name or IP address of the server to issue the request to. Default: 'localhost'.

**hostname**  Alias for host. To support url.parse(), hostname will be used if both host and hostname are specified.

Since you have provided both its taking hostname while processing get request

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback